# Linux command-line call not returning what it should from os.system?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, command-line, os.system

I need to make some command line calls to linux and get the return from this, however doing it as below is just returning `0` when it should return a time value, like `00:08:19`, I am testing the exact same call in regular command line and it returns the time value `00:08:19` so I am confused as to what I am doing wrong as I thought this was how to do it in python.

```
import os
retvalue = os.system("ps -p 2993 -o time --no-headers")
print retvalue
```

Comment: While I don't speak the python, you'll be wanting `popen`. 'Cause the test output from a command is *not* the same as it's return value...

Answer (score 100, accepted):

What gets returned is the return value of executing this command. What you see in while executing it directly is the output of the command in stdout. That 0 is returned means, there was no error in execution.

Use popen etc for capturing the output .

Some thing along this line:

```
import subprocess as sub
p = sub.Popen(['your command', 'arg1', 'arg2', ...],stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
output, errors = p.communicate()
print output
```

or

```
import os
p = os.popen('command',"r")
while 1:
    line = p.readline()
    if not line: break
    print line
```

ON SO : [Popen and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007855/popen-and-python)

Answer (score 25):

If you're only interested in the output from the process, it's easiest to use subprocess' [check_output](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["command", "arg1", "arg2"]);
```

Then output holds the program output to stdout. Check the link above for more info.

Comment: also recommended, if you don't need the output, subprocess.check_call(), which checks the process status and raises an error on failure. (2.4+) But that's not an answer to *this* question, which specifically needs to capture the output. Still, one of my favorites. :)

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way is like this:

```
import os
retvalue = os.popen("ps -p 2993 -o time --no-headers").readlines()
print retvalue
```

This will be returned as a list

Answer (score 8):

Your code returns `0` if the execution of the commands passed is successful and non zero if it fails. The following program works on python2.7, haven checked 3 and versions above. Try this code.

```
>>> import commands
>>> ret = commands.getoutput("ps -p 2993 -o time --no-headers")
>>> print ret
```

Comment: commands.getoutput('ls') throws a "Usage: commands [bnum]" error for me.

Comment: This module was removed in Python 3 which is a pity because it is more convenient than suprocess module.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's counter-intuitive and does not seem very pythonic, but it actually just mimics the unix API design, where these calld are C POSIX functions. Check [`man 3 popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) && [`man 3 system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)

Somewhat more convenient snippet to replace **os.system** that I use:

```
from subprocess import (PIPE, Popen)


def invoke(command):
    '''
    Invoke command as a new system process and return its output.
    '''
    return Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()


result = invoke('echo Hi, bash!')
# Result contains standard output (as you expected it in the first place).
```

Answer (score 2):

I can not add a comment to **IonicBurger** because I do not have "50 reputation" so
I will add a new entry.  My apologies.  **os.popen()** is the best for multiple/complicated commands (my opinion) and also for getting the return value in addition to getting stdout like the following more complicated multiple commands:

```
import os
out = [ i.strip() for i in os.popen(r"ls *.py | grep -i '.*file' 2>/dev/null; echo $? ").readlines()]
print "     stdout: ", out[:-1]
print "returnValue: ", out[-1]
```

This will list all python files that have the word *'file'* anywhere in their name.  The **[...]** is a list comprehension to remove (strip) the newline character from each entry.  The **echo $?** is a shell command to show the return status of the last command executed which will be the grep command and the last item of the list in this example.  the **2>/dev/null** says to print the *stderr* of the **grep** command to **/dev/null** so it does not show up in the output.  The **'r'** before the **'ls'** command is to use the raw string so the shell will not interpret metacharacters like **'*'** incorrectly.  This works in python 2.7.  Here is the sample output:

```
      stdout:  ['fileFilter.py', 'fileProcess.py', 'file_access..py', 'myfile.py']
 returnValue:  0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but purely using `os.system`, the following's a valid way of accessing the data returned by the `ps` call. Note: it does use a pipe to write the data to a file on disk. *And* OP didn't specifically ask for a solution using `os.system`.

```
>>> os.system("ps > ~/Documents/ps.txt")
0    #system call is processed.
>>> os.system("cat ~/Documents/ps.txt")
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9927 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
10063 pts/0    00:00:00 python
12654 pts/0    00:00:00 sh
12655 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
0
```

accordingly,

```
>>> os.system("ps -p 10063 -o time --no-headers > ~/Documents/ps.txt")
0
>>> os.system("cat ~/Documents/ps.txt")
00:00:00
0
```

No idea why they are all returning zeroes though.

Comment: the returning zeroes are the exit codes, meaning that the commands were executed succesfully

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, Popen function of subprocess python module is the answer. For example,

```
import subprocess
..
process = subprocess.Popen("ps -p 2993 -o time --no-headers", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

okey I believe the fastest way it would be

```
import os
print(os.popen('command').readline())
x = _
print(x)
```

Comment: print(os.popen('command').read()) if you want to return all the output. readline is only going to return the first line. Also worth noting that this is Python3 syntax.

Comment: `_` is only set in the python interactive shell; this won't work in a script.

Answer (score -1):

```
using commands module
import commands
""" 
Get high load process details 
"""
result = commands.getoutput("ps aux | sort -nrk 3,3 | head -n 1")
print result  -- python 2x
print (result) -- python 3x
```