# How to check type of files without extensions?

Tags: python, filesystems, identification

I have a folder full of files and they don't have an extension. How can I check file types? I want to check the file type and change the filename accordingly. Let's assume a function `filetype(x)` returns a file type like `png`. I want to do this:

```
files = os.listdir(".")
for f in files:
    os.rename(f, f+filetype(f))
```

How do I do this?

Comment: rel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python

Comment: You'll have to be more specific with regard to `file types`.  Do you mean determining if it's a gif, png, bmp or jpg?  Do you just want to know if it's text/binary?  Executable?

Comment: @thg435, once you have the MIME type is there a way to convert that to a suitable filename extension?

Comment: @Mark: yes, use [guess_extension](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_extension), but actually, mimetypes won't work here, because it's based on file extensions. What they need is libmagic (see the 2nd answer on the link).

Comment: @thg435, it's not very robust - `application/jpeg` returns `.jpe` rather than the preferred `.jpg`. It really does appear to be guessing.

Comment: @Mark: no, it doesn't guess, it takes infos straight from the local mime database (/etc/mime.types or whatever). `jpe` is just happens to be the first match for image/jpeg, try `guess_all_extensions` to see them all.

Comment: @JoeFish determinig if it's a gif, png, pdf, or jpg or something else

Comment: try this https://pypi.org/project/filetype/ ?

Comment: Voting to reopen. This question is asking about determining the type of files without extensions, whereas the linked question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/43580/3216427, is about mime types, which are determined by looking at the extension. That's precisely what OP says they don't have.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

There are Python libraries that can recognize files based on their content (usually a header / magic number) and that don't rely on the file name or extension.

If you're addressing many different file types, you can use [`python-magic`](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic).  That's just a Python binding for the well-established `magic` library.  This has a good reputation and (small endorsement) in the limited use I've made of it, it has been solid.

The native [imghdr](http://docs.python.org/library/imghdr.html) library can be useful, but is deprecated since Python 3.11 and will be removed in Python 3.13.

If you need dependency-free (pure Python) file type checking, see [`filetype`](https://github.com/h2non/filetype.py).

Comment: The package [`python-magic-win64`](https://github.com/axnsan12/python-magic-win64) worked for me in Windows

Comment: [imghdr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html) with combination of [filetype](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/) worked for me in windows

Comment: The [imghdr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html#module-imghdr) module is deprecated since version 3.11

Comment: For python magic there are dependencies: Windows: `pip install python-magic-bin`
and Linux: `sudo apt-get install libmagic1` are required.

Comment: Also note that **filetype** and **python-magic** can produce quite different results, e.g. if you have a `*.docx` file, then filetype reports `"application/zip"` as MIME type (because essentialy a docx file consists of a zip container containing XML documents) while python-magic says `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"`, which is more precise (i.e. it looks inside the ZIP container).

Comment: The latest release of *filetype* module could correctly guess `.docx` file as `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Answer (score 77):

The [Python Magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) library provides the functionality you need.

You can install the library with `pip install python-magic` and use it as follows:

```
>>> import magic

>>> magic.from_file('iceland.jpg')
'JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01'

>>> magic.from_file('iceland.jpg', mime=True)
'image/jpeg'

>>> magic.from_file('greenland.png')
'PNG image data, 600 x 1000, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced'

>>> magic.from_file('greenland.png', mime=True)
'image/png'
```

The Python code in this case is calling to [libmagic](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/3/libmagic/) beneath the hood, which is the same library used by the *NIX `file` command. Thus, this does the same thing as the subprocess/shell-based answers, but without that overhead.

Comment: Beware that the debian/ubuntu package called python-magic is different to the pip package of the same name.  Both are `import magic` but have incompatible contents.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16203777/3189 for more.

Comment: @Richard Do you mind elaborating on the overhead aspect? What makes the `python-magic` library more efficient then using subprocess approaches?

Comment: Superb answer. If you see `failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation`, then run `brew install libmagic` and try it again

Answer (score 11):

On unix and linux there is the [`file`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-determine-file-type/) command to guess file types.  There's even a [windows port](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm).

From the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file):

> File tests each argument in an attempt to classify it.  There are three
>   sets  of tests, performed in this order: filesystem tests, magic number
>   tests, and language tests.  The first test  that   succeeds  causes  the
>   file type to be printed.

You would need to run the `file` command with the `subprocess` module and then parse the results to figure out an extension.

**edit:**  Ignore my answer.  Use Chris Johnson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10937927/1322401) instead.

Comment: +1 I didn't realize `file` did that much.  `# file arc.gif
arc.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 234 x 269`

Comment: Well, I was hoping someone had a better answer.  There's still a lot of work for the OP, it's not a simple function call.

Comment: +1 One benefit with using the `file` command is that it is native on (most?) Linux distributions while the `python-magic` is not and has to be downloaded and installed before it can be used. This is somewhat of a problem if the script using the module is supposed to be portable.

Answer (score 10):

In the case of images, you can use the `imghdr` module.

```
>>> import imghdr
>>> imghdr.what('8e5d7e9d873e2a9db0e31f9dfc11cf47')  # You can pass a file name or a file object as first param. See doc for optional 2nd param.
'png'
```

[Python 2 imghdr doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html)
[Python 3 imghdr doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html)

Comment: imghdr is deprecated in python 3.11 https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html - `filetype` looks to work well in place of it https://pypi.org/project/filetype/

Answer (score 7):

```
import subprocess as sub
p = sub.Popen('file yourfile.txt', stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
output, errors = p.communicate()
print(output)
```

As Steven pointed out, [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) is the way. You can get the command output by the way above as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791465/python-os-system-for-command-line-call-linux-not-returning-what-it-should) said

Comment: And how do you capture the output?

Comment: @MarkRansom sorry that was not a good way, please see my updates above

Comment: If you need to interact with your system instead of using a Python library, the solution is suboptimal most of the time, because it is likely not useful in other operating systems with a different API.

Answer (score 6):

You can also install the official `file` binding for Python, a library called `file-magic` (it does not use ctypes, like `python-magic`).

It's available on PyPI as [file-magic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/file-magic) and on Debian as [python-magic](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python-magic). For me this library is the best to use since it's available on PyPI and on Debian (and probably other distributions), making the process of deploying your software easier.
I've [blogged about how to use it](http://blog.justen.eng.br/2016/02/detecting-file-type-and-encoding-in-python.html), also.

Answer (score 4):

With newer subprocess library, you can now use the following code (*nix only solution):

```
import subprocess
import shlex

filename = 'your_file'
cmd = shlex.split('file --mime-type {0}'.format(filename))
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
mime_type = result.split()[-1]
print mime_type
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BTW, you should not use a str.split() on a cmd line. use shlex.split(cmd) insteed.

Comment: Instead of using `shlex.split`, why not just run `subprocess.check_output(['file', '--mime-type', filename])`?

Answer (score 4):

also you can use this code (pure python by 3 byte of header file):

```
full_path = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, pathfile)

try:
    image_data = open(full_path, "rb").read()
except IOError:
    return "Incorrect Request :( !!!"

header_byte = image_data[0:3].encode("hex").lower()

if header_byte == '474946':
    return "image/gif"
elif header_byte == '89504e':
    return "image/png"
elif header_byte == 'ffd8ff':
    return "image/jpeg"
else:
    return "binary file"
```

> without any package install [and update version]

Comment: How can I check for xlsx?

Comment: You can used by 4 or 8 bytes. XLSX(MS Office Open XML Format Document) => 50 4B 03 04 (4 Bytes) => ASCII (PK••) ***or*** XLSX(MS Office 2007 documents) => 50 4B 03 04 14 00 06 00 (8 Bytes) => ASCII (PK••••••)

Comment: this comment gives a very interesting idea, for me, it's pythonic although it is not accurate. It should be as Alya Mad's question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69561458/how-to-check-type-of-files-using-the-header-file-signature-magic-numbers and more extension https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Answer (score 0):

Only works for Linux but Using the "sh" python module you can simply call any shell command

https://pypi.org/project/sh/

pip install sh

> import sh
>
> sh.file("/root/file")

Output:
/root/file: ASCII text

Answer (score 0):

This code list all files of a given extension in a given folder recursively

```
import magic
import glob
from os.path import isfile

ROOT_DIR = 'backup'
WANTED_EXTENSION = 'sqlite'

for filename in glob.iglob(ROOT_DIR + '/**', recursive=True):
    if isfile(filename):
        extension = magic.from_file(filename, mime = True)
        if WANTED_EXTENSION in extension:
            print(filename)
```

https://gist.github.com/izmcm/6a5d6fa8d4ec65fd9851a1c06c8946ac