# How to test if a link target is a pdf file if the link does not contain .pdf

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium to scrape a bunch of files which are provided in a mix of formats and styles - trying to handle both html and pdf, and I've come across an issue when the target of a link is a pdf file, but the link itself does not contain '.pdf' [e.g.](http://www.mndaust.asn.au/Documents/Information-resources/MND-Aspects-of-care-for-the-primary-health-care-te.aspx), [and](http://resus.org.au/?wpfb_dl=17) (note that one automatically downloads, and one just displays the file - at least in chrome - so there may need to be a test for two different types of pdf targets as well?)

Is there a way to tell programmatically if the target of a link is pdf that is more intelligent than just checking if it ends in .pdf?

I can't just download the file no matter the content, because I have distinct handling for the html files, where I want to follow secondary links and see if I can find pdfs, which won't work if the target is a pdf directly.

ETA: The accepted answer worked perfectly - the linked potential dupe is for testing on file system, not for download so I don't think that's valid, and certainly the answer below is better for this situation.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python  could help resolve your probelm

Comment: @willie I don't understand what you think I've done wrong here?  Happy to edit my question if required, but it's not clear to me what has been missed from the posting guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium (or Chrome) checks the `'Content-Type'` headers and choose what to do. You can also check the `'Content-Type'` of a URL yourself use `requests` like below:

```
>>> r = requests.head('https://resus.org.au/?wpfb_dl=17')
>>> pprint.pprint(dict(r.headers))
{'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
  'Age': '8518',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Description': 'File Transfer',
  'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; '
  'filename="anzcor-guideline-6-compressions-apr-2021.pdf"',
    'Content-Length': '535677',
  'Content-Md5': '90AUQUZu0vFGJ7cBPvRxcg==',
  'Content-Security-Policy': 'upgrade-insecure-requests',
  'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
  'Date': 'Wed, 19 Jan 2022 11:20:06 GMT',
  'Expires': 'Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT',
  'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 19 Jan 2022 08:58:08 GMT',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Server': 'openresty',
  'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=300, max-age=31536000; '
  'includeSubDomains',
    'Vary': 'User-Agent',
  'X-Backend': 'local',
  'X-Cache': 'cached',
  'X-Cache-Hit': 'HIT',
  'X-Cacheable': 'YES:Forced',
  'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
  'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block'}
```

As you can see, the `'Content-Type'` of your two links are all `'application/pdf'`:

```
>>> r.headers['Content-Type']
'application/pdf'
```

So you can just check the output of `requests.head(link).headers['Content-Type']`, and do whatever you need.

---

For this moment (Jan 19 2022), the first link in your question redirects me to a 404 page. And the second one is still accessible, but it's needed to use HTTPS protocol by changing the link's start part from `http://` to `https://`.

But anyway, if the URL doesn't redirect you to any other page, this answer isn't out-of-date. If the URL does, please request the newest URL by checking the `status_code` if it's a 301:

```py
>>> r = requests.head('http://resus.org.au/?wpfb_dl=17')
>>> r.status_code
301
>>> r = requests.head('https://resus.org.au/?wpfb_dl=17')
>>> r.status_code
200
>>>
```

Comment: Well, I just reproduced the code you listed above and it gives me
'Content-Type': 'text/html;' for both links not 'application/pdf'. Any ideas what changed or what to change? I'd greatly appreciate this.

Comment: @KirylAleksandrovich I've tried it again, yes you're right. After many years, the links return something described in the header`'X-Cacheable': 'NO:HTTPS Redirect'`. This means the link should be started with `https://`, rather than HTTP. I've edited my code, please try again with the new code above.

Comment: Yeah, the new version works fine, thanks!