# response.write but for files with correct content-type?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Is there a way to return a file (ex. images, scripts) with correct content type with `response.write`? This is what I have been using:

```
with open(path) as f:
    self.response.write(f.read())
```

but this sets the content type as `text/html`. Or is `response.write` not the correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [an example using `mimetypes`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/latest/file-example.html) in the Webob documentation (webapp2 requests and responses are [Webob Request/Response objects](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/stable/index.html)). Documentation on `mimetypes` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html). `mimetypes` is a built-in python module mapping file extensions to MIME type.

The example I found includes this function:

```
import mimetypes
def get_mimetype(filename):
    type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
    # We'll ignore encoding, even though we shouldn't really
    return type or 'application/octet-stream'
```

You can use that function in your handler like so:

```
def FileHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    # I'm going to assume `path` is a route arg
    def get(self, path):
        # set content_type
        self.response.content_type = get_mimetype(path)
        with open(path) as f:
             self.response.write(f.read())
```

Note: using [`python-magic`](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) instead of `mimetypes` would work as well and might be worth looking into, as @Dan Cornilescu pointed out. He linked to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the content type to the header:

```
my_file = f.read()
content_type = my_file.headers.get('Content-Type', 'text/html')

self.response.headers.add_header("Content-Type",content_type)
self.response.write(my_file)
```

Comment: The problem is that the code might not know what the content type might be.

Comment: This *might* help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python

Comment: edited answer.  But, as Dan said, Python Magic should do the trick.