# How to check the type of incoming file

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv, text, types

I write function operates with some data. I start from reading data from file, put it into structure and then do some calculations.
My problem - incoming file can be txt, csv or xls (xlsx).
For different types of file I need to use different methods.

**So, my question is - how to check the type of incoming file.**

Now I use the next approach:

```
def main(filename):
    if '.txt' in filename:
        # use read_txt
    elif '.xls' in filename:
        print('there is no txt method')
    else:
        print('etc.')
```

But it is not perfect: for example if I create file `My.txt.xls` it fails.
I think about `try` and use all the reading functions one by one, but look like there is some more obvious way...

Comment: Although the question is old, the GitHub referenced has been updated in the last month. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python. So, I think it is still valid.

Comment: @Nick I didn't get it - your link put me on my own question.

Comment: Ooops! I've updated the comment. Sorry!