# Python Exception when a css file is not detected and how to detect a css file

Tags: python, css, exception

Which python function/method/class can I use to detect whether a file is a css file or not?

Which Python exception should I use to indicate that a css file is not detected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check type of files without extensions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python)

Comment: just doing a filename[-4:] == ".css" should work for the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type

Maybe your own exception will be the best choice, for example

```
class CssFileTypeError(Exception):
    pass

raise CssFileTypeError
```

Comment: Thanks. I chose this solution as it uses `minetypes`, a standard python 3 module, and it can detect css type file. Also, the custom Exception is easy to implement. :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution A: Check the file extension. If the file ends with `.css` it's likely a CSS file. Example: `someFilePath[-4:] == ".css"`

Solution B: Try to parse the CSS file. Use `tinycss` or a similar module. If parsing fails the parser will throw an exception. (See: https://tinycss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parsing.html.)

Regarding exceptions: You can either a) go with something like `raise Exception("Not a CSS file")` or similar, or b) design a custom exception and raise it. Both things work, both have their advantages and disadvantages. What's best heavily depends on the context. I've no information about details of your implementation, so I can not tell you which option is better.