# I forwarded an SMS video from my phone using email. It arrives without an extension. What type is it?

Tags: video, sms, codec

I forwarded an SMS video from my phone using email.  It arrives without an extension.  What type is it?

I can play it in Windows Media and VLC Media Player but these then immediately close the file for some reason, so I can't inspect the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to the answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python)  The solution is:

```
import magic
magic.from_file('2502')
'ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, 3GPP'
```

Then the right file extension to add is ".mpeg4".

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.mp4` as extension? It's rare to see something like `myFile.mpeg4`