# How can i read a file type like “.mp3, .psd, .pdf” using python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read the file type of a file and transfer to another folder using python. 
Is there’s a code in python that can read file type like “.mp3, .psd, .pdf, etc”

Thank you.

Comment: Do you only care about the extension, or are you trying to identify the type of file regardless of the extension?

Comment: Im trying to identify the type of a file so that i can create a function that creates a folder with the file type name on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check type of files without extensions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check what is called "magic".
Take a look at python libraries that deal with it like

https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/

In Unix (like) environments (linux, BSD, MacOs) you can use it as a command too, try `file <file_name>`:
https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic

Comment: You are welcome, let us know which solution you decided to use. It might be useful for people who have the same problem as you.