# Autodesk Forge download object, but cannot tell if it is a Revit model or zip file

Tags: autodesk-forge

I was downloading Revit models from BIM360 team hub via ForgeAPI using the following uri.

`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName`

All my `objectName` ended with `.rvt`. So I downloaded and saved them as `rvt` file.
However I noticed that some of the files cannot be opened by Revit. They are actually not `rvt` files but zip files. So I have to change the extension to `.zip` and unzip the file to get real 'rvt` files.

My Problem is that not all files is `zip` file. I cannot tell from the API because the URI I request is always ended with `.rvt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Unix OS provides the `file` command, a standard utility program for recognising the type of data contained in a computer file:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)

A `zip` file is directly recognised and reported like this:

```
$ file test_dataset.zip
test_dataset.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

A Revit RVT model is a Windows compound document file, so it generates the following output:

```
$ file little_house_2021.rvt
little_house_2021.rvt: Composite Document File V2 Document, Cannot read section info
```

Hence you can use the same algorithm as `file` does to distinguish between RVT and ZIP files.

Afaik, `file` just looks at the first couple of bytes in the given file.

The Python programming language offers similar utilities; try an Internet search
for [distinguish file type python](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=distinguish+file+type+python); the first hits explain
[How to check type of files without extensions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python)
and point to the [`filetype` Python project](https://pypi.org/project/filetype).

Other programming languages can provide similar functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I may not express clear. The problem is that. I download a file from "https://some_url/file.rvt" and save it to local as "file.rvt". However, this file is not always a true rvt file. Sometimes, even the download url is "https://some_url/file.rvt", the file itself's extension is rvt, but it is actually a zip file..I was seeking a way to tell if a file is rvt file or zip file regardless its extension.

Comment: I thought it is problem of Autodesk Forge. It marks the file to be a Revit file. But when you downloaded the file. It sometimes gives you a zip file rather than Revit file but still name it `.rvt`.

Comment: Just tried your method. `file` command does tell if the file is a zip file even its extension is `rvt`. Thank you so much.

Comment: My pleasure entirely. Glad it helped.