# How to guess a file extension with python?

Tags: python, file, file-extension, file-type

I have recently tried to make a  python code which takes a path of a file *without an extension* and determine what extension it has.

I was looking for something like the example below. In the example the extension is exe (but the code doesn't know that yet).

```
path = 'C:\\MyPath\\Example'
#takes the path above and guesses the programs extension:
extension = guess_extension(path)
#adds the extension to the path:
fullPath = path+extension
print(fullPath)
```

Output:

```
C:\MyPath\Example.exe
```

If you know a python module that would do that (or something similar), please list it below.



I have tried to use filetype (filetype.guess()) and mimetypes (mimetypes.guess_extension()) modules, but they would both return value of none.
I have also tried to use answers from many questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python), but that still didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check type of files without extensions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python)

Comment: Do you mean "guess" just by name? Or do you want to actually *check* from the file itself?

Comment: Your question is too vague. If this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python doesn't help you, you have to look at which files are not correctly identified and frame a question around that particular problem.

Comment: Answer to Mike Poole and Perry: No, that doesn't answer my question. I said filetype module didn't work for me and that is the answer to that question.

Comment: Do you mean you know the partial name of the file (i.e. extension unknown).  So in your example, you would want to find all files named "Example.*" (where * is wildcard)which would turn out to be Example.exe.  Is this correct ?

Comment: Reply to DarryIG: I want to take a single file named Example which is the only one named so in the dir, and check what extension it has based on something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the built in `glob` module ([`glob` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)) might be what you're looking for. This module provides Unix style pattern expansion functionality within Python.

In the following example the incomplete `path` variable has the `str` `.*` appended to it when passed to `glob.glob`. This essentially tells `glob.glob` to return a `list` of valid paths found within the host system that start the same as `path`, followed by a period (designating a file extension), with the asterisk matching any and all characters following those from `path + '.'`.

```py
import glob

path = r'C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\minidump-analyzer'

full = glob.glob(path+'.*')

print(full[0])
```

Output: `C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\minidump-analyzer.exe`

It is worth noting that the above is just an illustration of how `glob` could be leveraged as part of a solution to your question. Proper handling of unexpected inputs, edge cases, exceptions etc. should be implemented as required by the needs of your program.