# How to detect zstd compression?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, compression, zstd

I am currently working on a python application, that works with facebook api's. As we all know, facebook loves their own technology and is working with zstd for data compression.

The problem: facebook is returning either a uncompressed response with normal json or if the response is longer, it is responding with a zstd compressed json.

My current code is something like this:

```
import zstd
import json


def handle_response(response)
    json = None
    try:
        json = json.loads(zstd.decompress(response.content))
    except:
        json = json.loads(response.text)

    return json
```

I am currently wondering, if there is a more clean way to do this and even detect zstd.

Comment: What you have would be "cleaner" if you replace the bare `except` with some specific type of exception.

Comment: Compressed data will have a [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures), sometimes called magic number that identifies it. There is a [document that describes the format](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/blob/master/doc/zstd_compression_format.md) and gives the `zstd` magic number. There are [ways to check the magic number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10937350/3279716).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're doing is fine.

You could, I suppose, check to see if the stream starts with the four bytes `28 b5 2f fd`. If it doesn't, it's not a zstd stream. If it does, it *may* be a zstd stream. In the latter case, you would try to decompress and if it fails, you would fall back to just copying the input.

That turns out to be exactly the same as what you're already doing, since the first thing that `zstd.decompress` is doing is to look for that signature.

Comment: So basically:
`request.content.startswith(b"\x28\xb5\x2f\xfd")` thanks! :)

Comment: Or just do what you put in the question.

Comment: `28 b5 2f fd` may also render like this in some cases (Redis, for me): `(\xb5/\xfd`

Answer (score 0):

After excute python clause 'b = zstd.compress(str)',the byte array always starts with 'b'(\xb5/\xfd \x03\x19\x00' .
So you can use 'index()' function to judge.

------------------
Does anyone know how to decompress the content which is the http response output type 'applicaton/zstd' when using internet browser?
like below:

> ache-control: no-store
>  cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
>  cf-ray:
> 7a51c7dbad5efb2c-SJC
>  content-length: 1591
> **content-type: application/zstd**
>  date: Thu, 09 Mar 2023 07:59:49 GMT
>  nel:
> {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
> report-to:
> {"endpoints":[{"url":"https://a.nel.cloudflare.com/report/v3?s=K3U4RKcx6XOP1ekNoJGTilOIZ%2FR4f43q%2BBsvbmmbEkQFHWMJQ5JvhDFDbZFHqVczdsR0rzY24pO9h4kjeehrn3fs0H76%2FO2F612s%2F7%2FjQ%2F6LRjYIb%2BOsPsFOEzIzJTU0NwSyUEmTPW0%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
> server: cloudflare