# How to get the type of a file with python?

Tags: python, file, file-type

I want to find out the filetypes of some files with no file ending. [image]

The best case would be if I could get the same string you get in the file properties. Iam using Python and already tried with mimetypes, which doesn't worked.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check type of files without extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions)

Answer (score 1):

I think your question has been resolved in this issue on stackoverflow :

[check type of file without extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions)

hopes this help :)

Comment: If you believe the question is a duplicate, mark it as such, rather than answering it.  Click "close", select "duplicate", and enter the URL of the duplicate question.

Comment: Hello Tom, i'm starting SO so that's a nice advise,  but i can't seem to find the `close` button, maybe i do not have the right

Comment: It's directly below the question, to the left of the author box.  There are links to "Share", "Edit", "Follow", "Close", and "Flag".  Click "Close", then select "Duplicate" and enter the duplicate URL.  I'm not sure if some amount of reputation is needed to unlock it, but it's quite possible.

Comment: Yes it is indeed linked to reputation, i can see the 4 others button but not the close one, but i'll be sure to do it when i'll be allowed to on further questions :)

Comment: It looks like you need 3000 rep. to be able to cast close/reopen votes.  You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `file` command, executed via `subprocess`.

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['file', '/path/to/allcfgconv'])
```

The resulting string is a bit verbose; you'll have to parse the file type from it yourself.