# python subprocess.Popen vs os.popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to get the output of the following shell command in my python script,

```
hadoop fs -ls /projectpath/ | grep ^d | grep -v done | head -1 | awk {'print $8'}
```

I can successfully get the output through `os.popen` as follows:

```
import os
cmd = "hadoop fs -ls /projectpath/ | grep ^d | grep -v done | head -1 | awk {'print $8'}"
p = os.popen(cmd,"r")
while 1:
    line = p.readline()
    if not line: break
    print line
```

But `os.popen()` is deprecated since python 2.6 so I wanted to replace the above snippet with the `subprocess.Popen()` function.

But the code snippet for `subprocess.Popen()` below gives a different result than the code snippet above.

```
import subprocess as sub
import shlex
cmd = "hadoop fs -ls /projectpath/ | grep ^d | grep -v done | head -1 | awk {'print $8'}"
args = shlex.split(cmd)
p = sub.Popen(args,stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
output, errors = p.communicate()
print output
```

The above command just gives output for `'hadoop fs -ls /projectpath/'` part of the command.
I have tried consulting several references (http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects, [Python, os.system for command-line call (linux) not returning what it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791465/python-os-system-for-command-line-call-linux-not-returning-what-it-should)) for `subpocess.Popen()` but cannot get it to execute the command in the string cmd. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
cmd = "hadoop fs -ls /projectpath/ | grep ^d | grep -v done | head -1 | awk {'print $8'}"
p = sub.Popen(cmd,stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE, shell=True)
```