# Using os.system to print in Python using Linux

Tags: os.system

I have searched everywhere for this and could not find an answer. I am using os.system to print to a printer, but it prints it off as a portrait and I need it to print off as Landscape. I assume there is a simple way to add something within the os.system command to get this to work, but I cannot figure out what it is. This is how I am printing it off right now:

```
os.system('lp "file.png"')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `os.system('lp -o landscape "file.png"')`

Comment: I tried that, however, all it did was shift the image to the right side of the page. I also tried os.system('lpr -o landscape "file.png"').

Comment: Hmm, anything strange in the options if you use lpoptions -l?

Comment: The only thing that sticks out is the "Rotate/180 Rotate:" is marked as false instead of true. I would think if that would be true it would print properly? Outside of that, everything seems normal.

Comment: Turns out it was a bug in the printer software. I reverted it to a previous version and the -o landscape worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was a bug, but just a hint on convenience:

I usually replace **os.system** with the following snippet

```
from subprocess import (PIPE, Popen)


def invoke(command):
    '''
    Invoke process and return its output.
    '''
    return Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()
```

or if you want to be more comfortable with [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/), try

```
from sh import lp

lp('-o', 'landscape', 'file.png')
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791465/python-os-system-for-command-line-call-linux-not-returning-what-it-should?rq=1