# Why does python return 0 when I fire terminal commands?

Tags: python, terminal

I was experimenting with getting python to interact with my terminal, and i tried the following script, and it returned 0, when i expected it to show the contents of the current directory:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("ls")
0
```

Why does it do this? (note this is a mac command, as i'm on a mac)

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791465/python-os-system-for-command-line-call-linux-not-returning-what-it-should

Comment: That command does print the contents of the current directory, but only prints

Comment: look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system). It says the returned value is 0 when the command completes successfully.

Comment: BTW, I hope that this is just an example -- calling `ls` is the wrong way to get a list of filenames in Python (for many of the same reasons it's the wrong way to programatically get filenames in bash; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 5):

`0` is the exit status of `ls` when it completes successfully.

If you want to capture a list of filenames, you want its stdout, not its exit status. `os.system()` doesn't return that.

I'd suggest:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(["ls"]) # will raise an exception if ls fails
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. How would i make it so it prints the terminal output to the shell?

Comment: Eh? Using `os.system()` should *already* be passing output straight to stdout -- which won't make it accessible to Python as a variable, but *will* print it straight to the terminal your Python shell is using. If you want to capture output to a Python variable, see the update using the subprocess module for that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's how the `os.system` function works (From the python doc):

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in the format specified for wait()

In this case `0` is the return value of the `ls` command which means that the command was successful. The `system` function does not capture the `stdout` or `stderr`.

If you want to capture them, please use the `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 0):

It returns 0 as that is the exit code for the command (meaning it exited cleanly).

If you want the results from a command, I would recommend using the subprocess module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

Answer (score 0):

It is the `ls` exit code.

If you execute an invalid command, the response will be probably something different than zero.

```
>>> os.system("ls -wk")
ls: invalid line width: k
512
```