# calling linux shell in python with writing output in a text file

Tags: python, linux, shell, call

I would like to call system shell in a Python code and write the results in a text file. When I write this command:

```
call(["ls", "-lrt"])
```

The calling process works and print the files and folders list as an output on the screen. However, when I try to write the printed output in a text file (rather than screen), it does not work! I tried all these:

```
call(["ls", "-lrt", ">", "result.txt"])

call(["ls", "-lrt", "> result.txt"])

call(["ls -lrt > result.txt"])
```

But in the Linux shell this command "`ls -lrt > result.txt`" nicely works.

I am using Linux CentOS 7 and my Python version is 2.7.5.

I will be thankful if anyone can help me for this simple problem.

Comment: It has been already answered here using os.system
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791465/python-os-system-for-command-line-call-linux-not-returning-what-it-should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use e.g. [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) like this

```
subprocess.call(["ls",  "-lrt"], stdout=open("foo.txt",'w'))
```

The signature of the function

```
subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
```

is rather self-explanatory; *`stdin`* , *`stdout`* and *`stderr`* are meant for fileobjects like those returned by open()

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Just to know: what does 'w' means?

Comment: [that's for *write* access](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files); it truncates the target file if itexists.