# How to write os.system() info to text file?

Tags: python, operating-system, trace

I want to write information about this tracing in file:

```
site = input('Input URL:')
trac = os.system('tracert '+site)
```

but `trac` equals 0 and I don't know how to get access to os.system() information.

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```
trac = os.system('tracert '+site)
```

the return value is :

**Linux**

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in the format specified for wait().

or

**Windows**

> On Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell after running command, given by the Windows environment variable COMSPEC.

For more information about that see python's documentation about  [*os.system*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system).

But if you want to retrieve outputs of your system call then use [*subprocess.check_output* method of *subprocess* module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead and try to change your code like that :

```
import subprocess
site = input('Input URL:')
trac = subprocess.check_output(["tracert", site])
# Do something else
```

Formerly you can did it with *os.popen* but since Python 2.6 it's deprecated :

> Deprecated since version 2.6: All of the popen*() functions are obsolete. Use the subprocess module.

Comment: @TobySpeight fixed.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post the stackoverflow's thread on my answer so I put here :
[Python, os.system for command-line call (linux) not returning what it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791465/python-os-system-for-command-line-call-linux-not-returning-what-it-should)