# how to store multiple values from kapacitor into python variable using linux?

Tags: python, linux

This command gives multiple values.

```
kapacitor list tasks | grep -i enabled
```

I need to iterate through and store the output of the above command. I tried

```
enabled = os.system("kapacitor list tasks | grep -i enabled")
print enabled
```

Output for this command kapacitor list tasks | grep -i enabled

Alert_ALL_metrics_cpu                                  stream    enabled   true      ["metrics_NWNA"."autogen" "metrics_NN"."autogen"]
tAlert_ALL_metrics_memory_usage                         stream    enabled   true      ["metrics_NWNA"."autogen" "metrics_NN"."autogen"]
tAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline                           stream    enabled   true      ["oracle_NWNA"."autogen" "oracle_NN"."autogen"]
tAlert_NN_WMS_endpoint-message-count_MSE                stream    enabled   true      ["metrics"."autogen"]
tAlert_NN_ecom_version_check                            stream    enabled   true      ["metrics_NN"."autogen"]
tAlert_NN_ecom_version_check_all_farms                  stream    enabled   true      ["metrics_NN"."autogen"]
tAlert_NN_metrics_fileSystem                            stream    enabled   true      ["metrics_NN"."autogen"]
tAlert_NWNA_metrics_fileSystem                          stream    enabled   true      ["metrics_NWNA"."autogen"]

Comment: take a look at the subprocess module iso os.system.  E.g. subprocess.call(...,shell=True)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the os module, try using the subprocess module.

import subprocess

```
ele = subprocess.Popen(['kapacitor', 'list', 'tasks', '|', 'grep', '-i', 'enabled'] shell=True)
output, err = ele.communicate()
print(output)
```

This will store the output of the command ran inside the output(as a variable) then you can call it and do whatever you want with it from there

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what variable come with your "enable" but try below.

```
from subprocess import check_output

datas = []

data = check_output("kapacitor list tasks | grep -i enabled")

print (data)

for i, j, k in data:    # i,j,k are just three variables in example. Add more if needed.
    datas.append((i,j),(k))

print (datas[0])  # prints (i,j)
```

For other type of subprocess command check SO question: [Linux command-line call not returning what it should from os.system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791465/linux-command-line-call-not-returning-what-it-should-from-os-system)

Comment: While executing  this command kapacitor list tasks | grep -i enabled it will display the result as tAlert_ALL_metrics_cpu                                  stream    enabled   true      ["metrics_NWNA"."autogen" "metrics_NN"."autogen"]
tAlert_ALL_metrics_memory_usage                         stream    enabled   true      ["metrics_NWNA"."autogen" "metrics_NN"."autogen"]
tAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline                           stream    enabled   true      ["oracle_NWNA"."autogen" "oracle_NN"."autogen"]

Comment: ...should be fixed now. `os.system` just prints the output without returning it as result (in this case a list form). The latter you can use to do whatever you want to do with it.